# Is is possible to do something with this NMR token send to ethereum wallet?

Tags: myetherwallet

You can see the transaction [here](https://etherscan.io/token/Numeraire?a=0xb8a3F6895486348485E3eD7E08d7980848bB139c): 
Too much money for sure and for me. Is it lost? Hope not, tried to send by using *myetherwallet* they ask to have at least 0.1 ETH (30$), I have only 2$.

Is it possible to send via downloading full block-chain?

Comment: You should have plenty. Just set the gas price low on myetherwallet,  set the gas limit to around 100k, and it should transfer fine. No need to run a full client.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to transfer 651 NMR from address 0xb8a3F6895486348485E3eD7E08d7980848bB139c to some place else.

To fix your problem, you just need to sign a transaction with a higher gas limit. Try with a gas limit of `50000` [instead of `23600`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x563e84ea629ad932cd6fb72f859e3fc8045edd78d1b25c3707995454440cad14). Using [ethgasstation calculator](https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php), running a transaction with 50k gas limit and a gas price of 21gwei will come to a tx cost of $0.0293/0.000105ETH which you have in your address, so this will succeed.

In short, up your gas limit to overcome the "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]" exception & get a successful transaction.